# Spring repository does not find a `findBy*` method and marks the transaction for rollback, causing persistence failures

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

### Relavent code

#### Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_FEATURE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "FEATURE_SEQ", sequenceName = "SOME_FEATURE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"featuredItems"})
@ToString(exclude = {"featuredItems"})
public class SomeFeatureEntity implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOME_FEATURE_SEQ")
private Long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Date created;

private String name;

private String featureType = "Text";

@Column(name = "feature_description")
private String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "feature")
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Set<SubFeatureEntity> featuredItems;

public Set<SubFeatureEntity> getFeaturedItems() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(featuredItems);
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
private Date modified;
}
```

#### Repository

```
    @Repository
public interface SomeFeatureEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeFeatureEntity, Long>{
    SomeFeatureEntity findByName(String name);
}
```

#### Dependencies

I do not control the versions, can't upgrade

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Ingalls-SR20</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.23.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

#### The test

This has been sanitized to I do not get yelled at by bean counters for exposing IP - my hands are tied here.

```
@Transactional
@Test
public void testFindByFeaturesName() {
    assertTrue(TestTransaction.isActive());
    FeatureEntity featureEntity;
    featureEntity = featureEntityRepository.findByName(TEST_FEATURE);
    FeatureManyRelationEntity FeatureManyRelationEntity = new FeatureManyRelationEntity();
    FeatureManyRelationEntity.setCreated(now);
    FeatureManyRelationEntity.setFeatures(featureManyRelationEntity);
    FeatureManyRelationEntity.setFeature(featureEntity);
    // This assertion passes - must be a different transaction
    assertTrue(TestTransaction.isActive());

    FeatureManyRelationEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(FeatureManyRelationEntity);
    // This assertion is never executed the flush above does not bother to execute.
    assertTrue(TestTransaction.isActive());
    Set<FeatureManyRelationEntity> featuresFeatures = FeatureManyRelationEntityRepository.findByFeatures(featureManyRelationEntity);
    assertNotNull(featuresFeatures);
    assertEquals(1, featuresFeatures.size());
    for (FeatureManyRelationEntity e : featuresFeatures) {
        assertEquals(TEST_FEATURE, e.getFeature().getName());
        assertEquals(TEST_Features_ITEM, e.getFeatures().getName());
    }
}
```

#### Error message

```
> 2020-08-25 13:51:04,471 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.j.r.query.JpaQueryFactory - Looking up query for method findByName
2020-08-25 13:51:04,472 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.j.repository.query.NamedQuery - Looking up named query SomeFeatureEntity.findByName
2020-08-25 13:51:04,472 [main] DEBUG o.h.j.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Mark transaction for rollback
2020-08-25 13:51:04,472 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.j.repository.query.NamedQuery - Did not find named query SomeFeatureEntity.findByName

> Note that the transaction is doomed to fail above even before the test starts
The folloing logs show that there is no problem actually `running`  the findByName method

>2020-08-25 13:51:06,681 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@55f26df5] for key [public abstract com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.entity.SomeFeatureEntity com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.SomeFeatureEntityRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)] to thread [main]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,681 [main] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Don't need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByName]: This method isn't transactional.
2020-08-25 13:51:06,681 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@641312f] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@90181ca] bound to thread [main]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,681 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl - Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from SomeFeatureEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.name=:name
2020-08-25 13:51:06,684 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@641312f] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@90181ca] bound to thread [main]
Hibernate: select Somefeatureent0_.id as id1_3_, Somefeatureent0_.created as created2_3_, Somefeatureent0_.Somefeature_description as Somefeature_3_3_, Somefeatureent0_.Somefeature_type as Somefeature_4_3_, Somefeatureent0_.modified as modified5_3_, Somefeatureent0_.name as name6_3_ from ec_Somefeature Somefeatureent0_ where Somefeatureent0_.name=?
2020-08-25 13:51:06,685 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
2020-08-25 13:51:06,685 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.entity.SomeFeatureEntity#7]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,686 [main] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.entity.SomeFeatureEntity#7]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,686 [main] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.entity.SomeFeatureEntity#7]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,686 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@55f26df5] for key [public abstract com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.entity.SomeFeatureEntity com.myCompany.myDepartment.product.storage.impl.repository.SomeFeatureEntityRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)] from thread [main]
```

> All good so far since an actual transaciton is not yet needed.

```
>2020-08-25 13:51:06,686 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@44653789] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(java.lang.Object)] to thread [main]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,690 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2020-08-25 13:51:06,691 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6731203d] for key [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl@67b95f82] bound to thread [main]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,691 [main] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,693 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@641312f] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@90181ca] bound to thread [main]
Hibernate: call next value for SOME_FEATURE_SEQ
2020-08-25 13:51:06,700 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator - Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Long[16]]
2020-08-25 13:51:06,701 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 16, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
2020-08-25 13:51:06,708 [main] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@641312f] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@90181ca] bound to thread [main]
```

> Error below (TransactionRequiredException) is misleading. There is/was a transaction bound to the thread, it's just marked for rollback, os it's useless for  persist.

```
>2020-08-25 13:51:06,709 [main] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush] after exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

This causes an issue only when persisting. The look up itself works fine.
The issue here is not that there is no named query. I know there isn't. I would have expected Spring to create one based on the name of the repository method and move on. Instead it marks the transaction for rollback, and does not attempt the eventual persist on a different entity.
Please help if you can.

Comment: could you put your entity class as well?

Comment: @SagarGangwal I do not have Skype, but thanks for the offer. I will add my entity class.

Comment: You say the error occurs only when persisting, but haven't provided the code that does that. Hibernate is calling a sequence on the persist apparently, more info on that would be useful, the entity class, and any relavent transaction demarcation.

Comment: @Your entity class have attribute as `name`??

Comment: @SagarGangwal - Yes, it does, see code above.

Comment: @Prashant Have you tried with `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` on your that persist method??

Comment: FeatureManyRelationEntityRepository ... has the saveAndFlush called on it ... can you show the wiring/type of this class ... starting variable names with caps makes it a little confusing as to whether that is actually a static method call or not. My hunch that attempting to manage the flushing of the session within a test marked Transactional is causing you some pain.

Comment: Could you please add a full test class with that test method and all related annotations?

Comment: All of you above - it's not fair to all of you trying ot help me,  that I do not give you access to the full code. Let me re-create the problem with a simple application that has no proprietary logic and publish it.

Comment: @Prashant I think you will find a solution with that simplified code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. It turns out my issue was wrong wiring. Unbeknownst to me, we were giving the transaction manager a *non-managed* entity manager. Once I fixed that, the code started working properly. This test did uncover a real issue. As it turned out, this had nothing to do with the `findBy` method.

Answer (score 1):

What i understood as other user suggested try with CRUDRepository rather than JPA.

As there is multiple error i am able to see. For findByName if issue is there, in that case your application itself will not get up and application starting it's throw an error that no property found with name and all.
For **`TransactionRequiredException`**, you need to manage with **`@Transactional`** annotation with [**`propagation`**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation) attribute.

Also, just try to provide some attributes like **`propagation`** and **`rollbackFor`**  for **`@Transactional`** annotation.

And one more point make sure , you had imported @Transactional from this package **`@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`**.

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    @Test
    public void testFindByFeaturesName() {
        assertTrue(TestTransaction.isActive());
        FeatureEntity featureEntity;
        featureEntity = featureEntityRepository.findByName(TEST_FEATURE);
        FeatureManyRelationEntity FeatureManyRelationEntity = new FeatureManyRelationEntity();
        FeatureManyRelationEntity.setCreated(now);
        FeatureManyRelationEntity.setFeatures(featureManyRelationEntity);
        FeatureManyRelationEntity.setFeature(featureEntity);
        // This assertion passes - must be a different transaction
        assertTrue(TestTransaction.isActive());
    
        FeatureManyRelationEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(FeatureManyRelationEntity);
        // This assertion is never executed the flush above does not bother to execute.
        assertTrue(TestTransaction.isActive());
        Set<FeatureManyRelationEntity> featuresFeatures = FeatureManyRelationEntityRepository.findByFeatures(featureManyRelationEntity);
        assertNotNull(featuresFeatures);
        assertEquals(1, featuresFeatures.size());
        for (FeatureManyRelationEntity e : featuresFeatures) {
            assertEquals(TEST_FEATURE, e.getFeature().getName());
            assertEquals(TEST_Features_ITEM, e.getFeatures().getName());
        }
    }
```

Or in worst case you just try by removing transaction annotation from this method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I remove `@Transactional` from the method, it's not a real test.

Answer (score 0):

Using CrudRepository will automaticly query bij Name when using `findByName(String name)`.
It will query based on Name, which is a property of your entity.

I'm not sure if JPA Repo does the same, but I'm using Crud and this works for me. Maybe JPA requires a manual query and Crud does not.

From what I understand from your error, JPA does not have a query for FindByName:

```
2020-08-25 13:51:04,472 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.j.repository.query.NamedQuery - Did not find named query SomeFeatureEntity.findByName
```

Crud will provide the query for you, give it a try.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: I am compiling, as I type but reservations are 1- JPA Repo inherits CrudRepo 2- I have to give up paging and sorting for this.

Comment: While  I appreciate the suggestion, I really need paging and sorting, so in this situation, I can't use this approach.